# Problem deploying a Bitbucket repo to Azure Storage

Tags: azure, bitbucket, azure-storage, bitbucket-pipelines

I've been trying to deploy my web app on Bitbucket to Azure Storage using Bitbucket Pipelines. I'm having issues with the `SOURCE` option. I need to copy the entire source code in the current repository, but `SOURCE` option seems to require a directory name.

My pipeline script is something like this:

```
- pipe: microsoft/azure-storage-deploy:2.0.0
    variables:
      SOURCE: './*'
      DESTINATION: 'https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer'
```

How can I deploy everything in current repository?

Comment: The documentation https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/azure-storage-deploy/src/master/README.md does not say anything about glob pattern; the `SOURCE` property can either be a file or folder path; I haven´t tested it, but I would expect that if the `SOURCE` property indicates a folder path, everything within that folder should go into the target blob-container or folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed now.
There is a constant `$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR` which holds current repository.

You can find more pre-defined constants here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/variables-in-pipelines-794502608.html